# Как сделать запуск JSP, JConsole на windows 10?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, powershell

Как подключить JSP и Jconsole ??? 
java version "1.8.0_241" 
на оракл пишут, что файлы запуска можно найти в папке Bin, но к сожалению у меня не получилось обнаружить файлы там, очень нужно для отслеживания многопоточности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываете командную строку и вводите команду 
`where java`

И смотрите установлена ли у вас java? И где она установлена. 
Ответ на команду будет что-то вроде
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe`

Проходите до папки `bin` и от туда ручками сможете запустить **jconsole.exe**